# Why when I start phpmyadmim this writting appears?

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, openssl, xampp

I start on Xammp Apache and MySQL but when I click on admin instead of opening the phpmyadmin page I see this writing:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl
```

What I have to do in order to solve this issue.

p.s. I imagine that I have to install this two files but in which folder I have to put them?

Comment: Maybe you don't have `mysqli` and `openssl` in your machine.

Comment: @MaverickFabroa Maybe but where I have to put them?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: @AndyAbiHaidar win 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with the XAMPP version 8.0.3 and the suggested solution was to reinstall XAMPP using the version 7.3.27. Also, try clear the cache before re-installing the XAMPP

1. Uninstall XAMPP 8.0.3
2. Got to Local disk (C)
3. Delete file xampp
4. Clear cache memory on webpage
5. Right click Local Disk (C) > Properties > Disk Cleaup > Check all > Ok
6. Install xampp 7.3.27

I hope that the above can be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had (maybe) the same issue. I first installed 8.x and then installed 7.4, but that didn't help.

When I tried to run the php.exe it showed an error on line 736 inside the php.ini.

I guess the problem was that XAMPP was installed to a location where a folder contained a space (Program Files (x86)). Under line 736 (maybe different for you) inside the php.ini the path was not put inside apostrophes. Slap some apostrophes on there and it should work.

**Error inside php.ini**

[image: error inside php.ini]

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I am facing such an issue when I have changed my php.ini (.../xampp/php.ini).
There are three php.ini files as

1. php.ini
2. php.ini-production
3. php.ini-development
   I have replaced the php.ini file to  php.ini-backup and rename php.ini-production to php.ini

so I have replaced back my php.ini-backup to php.ini and the issue is gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@ozzy has said is right,
but forgot to mention 1 main point (multiple installs)

this appears when this version of xampp is installed multiple times (without un-installing the previous).

- uninstall the xampp being shown in programs list (programs and features).
- restrated pc.
- then deleted all the directories of xampp (may they be on any drive).
- if the data is important, rename all xampp directories.
- restarted pc.
- installed xampp again.
- -- thats all.